# Towel warmer (hardwired) - electrical code considerations

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

We have a new towel warmer, which I believe would not technically comply with codes in the U.S.  Electrical connections need to be inside junction boxes, unless I'm mistaken, and this towel warmer does not include a junction box.  So it looks like the connection would need to be made inside the faceplate of the towel warmer mounting bracket, from what I see in these instructions.

I've seen a lot of towel warmers without junction boxes included (some have them), so it's unclear where the connection is supposed to be made.  (I've also seen nobody complaining online about failing an inspection due to a towel warmer.)  Are all these towel warmers being sold in the U.S. violating code if they are hard wired?

Or is there a water proof faceplate I can buy made for this situation?

Also, our town requires metal conduit which further complicates things.

[image]

Here is a picture of a different towel warmer with a junction box that would be code compliant I think:

[image]

Comment: What make and model is the unit in question? Does it have a *listing* label (UL, ETL, CSA)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mine have always had plugs, if you want to hard wire it use flex , I us liquid tight flex all the time depending on what it is for I may use non metallic liquid tight , most of my systems take a beating and metallic holds up better especially in cold conditions. But this is an option.

Comment: There is already come flexible metal conduit ready to go behind the wall.  (actually it's new construction so there's no drywall yet).  But the main problem I'm having is that there is no junction box.  I added a second picture to show what I mean by an included junction box.  I'm not sure where I would legally connect the wires without a junction box.

Comment: Why not add the j box behind where the power goes in, you can go from flex to a box.

Comment: I think the mounting screws are meant to go into wood or drywall, not into a metal junction box.  There would be nothing to screw into.  The wire might be long enough to go into a junction box off to the side maybe.  But that might look weird.  But that might be the only choice.  I might just see (ask my wife) if we can use the plug in option.

Comment: Oh I think I get it.  The instructions show only 3 out of the 4 footings screwed into the wall.  The 4th footing has the wire coming out of it, so it is not screwed in.  So you are right.  Make my own junction box behind the footing.

Comment: Never heard of a towel warmer until you explained it months ago... i need a towel cooler down here..+

Comment: @JACK, not sure what you mean by I explained it months ago... don't get it.  My wife wants a towel warmer,.  I'd prefer just to move to a warmer climate.

Comment: @Dave I was directing this comment to Ed Beal.  No "@" is needed for the person writing the answer or question. If I was directing it toward you, I would have done "@Dave".

Comment: Hi Jack, sorry for the mix up.  Thanks!